# Django timezone models.DateTimeField does not have seconds via DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model which has DateTimeField

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now)
```

in database it has the Datetime with seconds `2021-07-27 07:51:18.87329`

However when returning this in `Django-Restful-Framework`, it doesn't have seconds.

like

```
class GenreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        objs = Genre.objects.all()
        custom_data = {
            'items': GenreSerializer(objs, many=True).data
        }
        return Response(custom_data) 


class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('id','pub_date')
```

Somehow it shows like `"pub_date": "07/27/2021 07:51P"`

Why seconds are omitted??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pub_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format=""%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M:%S %p"")
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('id','pub_date')
```

Just use python datetime format here and it should work for you

Comment: Thank you it works. It is also helpful to understand `serializer`

Comment: You are welcome. I feel glad to help you.